# Android change stroke and gradient color under shape programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, gradient

**text_lines.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/drawable_textLines"
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/textBorderColor" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:startColor="@color/textBorderColor"
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:type="linear"/>

        <!--<solid android:color="#11999595" />-->

    </shape>
</item>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
 int backgroundColor = ((ViewHolder) holder).backroundColor;

 LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ((ViewHolder) holder).title.getBackground();
 GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.drawable_textLines);
 bgShape.mutate();
 bgShape.setColor(backgroundColor);
```

**And the text view in my layout:**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:background="@drawable/text_lines"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

What I want to achieve is change the color of both the *stroke* and *start color* of the gradient under shape inside `text_lines.xml` at runtime. 
My code above changes the whole background of the gradient to the desired color but has 2 problems:

1. It does not have the gradient effect specified in the xml
2. The color of the stroke is not changed.

Anyone knows how to solve this?